# Check which repos are in sync with the remote from a list of repos?

Tags: git

I have a directory that contains a bunch of git repos. All these repos have remotes in Github and Gitlab. What command can I execute to check, for each of these repos:

1- Which ones have uncommited changes.
2- Which ones have commits that have not been synced to the remote.

Comment: Have you tried [git status](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-status)?

Comment: As @JimWright said, you can use subprocess to capture the output of git status and build your logic out of it

Comment: @JimWright git status is for a single repo.

Comment: *Every* Git command is for a single repo. So you will likely have to write a script that does something simply for every repository.

Answer (score 1):

I keep this script around which lets me apply a git command to every subdirectory:

```
#!/usr/bin/env zsh

submodules=("${(@f)$(find . -type d -depth 1)}")
for submodule in $submodules
do
    print "=== $submodule"
    git --work-tree=$submodule --git-dir=$submodule/.git $*
    print
done
```

[Edit] just to clarify: the `submodule` variable name in the script  really should have been `subdirectory`. The script has nothing to do with git's submodule feature.